# CSS: Removing the period in list-style-type: decimal

Tags: css

I have an ol using decimal list styles:

```
ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

The numbering is working fine, but how do I remove the period? Instead of showing:

```
1. First
2. Second
```

I want to show:

```
1 First
2 Second
```

Comment: Don’t use list-style, use a CSS counter instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom counter and generated content. There isn't a pre-defined [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) that allows for that format.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: list;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  counter-increment: list;
  position: relative;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(list);
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ol>
```